# not able to connect to a remote Database using my Nexus S

Tags: android, timeout, connection, nexus-s, remote-server

I have been trying to connect my Nexus S  to a remote database (which is set up in my local computer).

In the local computer I have set up a MYSQL database and  I am accessing it using php which I am activating from my android application.

My program is working fine when I am testing it from the emulator and connecting to the other local machine(where the server is set up) using HTTP post method.

So I have figured out there is some connectivity issue when I am trying to connect to it using my Nexus S.

Someone told about using the external IP or static IP for the local computer while connecting to the local computer, which I am not able to figure it out.

This is the log I'm getting when trying to connect and getting a Timeout exception.

```
D/dalvikvm(  368): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 51% free 3362K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 58ms

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyServiceState: 0 home Vodafone Vodafone 40445 (manual) UMTS CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=3

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyServiceState: 0 home Vodafone Vodafone 40445 (manual) HSDPA CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=8

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyServiceState: 0 home Vodafone Vodafone 40445 (manual) UMTS CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=3

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyServiceState: 0 home Vodafone Vodafone 40445 (manual) HSDPA CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false

I/TelephonyRegistry(  107): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=null interfaceName=rmnet0 networkType=8
```

if anyone can give me some points on it

Comment: So are you trying to connect over the phone network to your home server pc, or do you want to connect over wifi to your pc over the local network?

Comment: I am trying to connect from the phone network to my office PC where the Database server  is set up.!!!!!

Comment: Ok, so you need to make sure you can get through your office firewall... You may need to specify a port in the app, map it on the office router to the specific pc with your server app on it. you may have done this already - if so i'm not sure.

Comment: So u mean to say i need to implement port forwarding .... ie  the connection getting routed to my server machine through the main office router.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the logs itself are fine. We are developing a streaming app and we got the same logs while songs are streamed from the mobile 3G network.

As other mentioned in comments, it is most likely that the logs are not related to your connectivity problem.

The Timeout itself probably means that the host your trying to reach is not accessible.